# How to say that something has already reached to some point

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

*Till* preposition is used to describe *upto some point of time*. I want some preposition that can be used for *place (distance)*.
For example, I have the following sentences (maybe,sentences are wrong).

> Yesterday, there was too much rain for three hours and water had reached till the last step of the entrance.

> Vasco da Gama was not the only man who discovered a sea route to India. An earlier explorer Bartolomev Diaz had reached till the southern tip of Africa.

I want to emphasize in first sentence that water had already reached last step. And in second sentence that Diaz had already reached the southern tip of Africa.

However, Till can be used for time-frame only. What is the appropriate preposition for above sentences? And also, how can it be used in question? E.g., While giving direction on phone, I wanted to ask my friend that upto what point he has already reached in the way. I asked him *Where have you reached till?* How can we phrase question in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: No preposition is needed - the paragraph after the quotations uses the correct construction.

Comment: @Kate Bunting and is this question *Where have you reached till?* correct?

Comment: No - you could say "What point have you reached?", but "How far have you got?" would be more natural.

Comment: @Kate Bunting can I say *where have you reached up to*? Or suppose in history,  some king has invaded territory and managed to reach the middle point but couldn't go further. Then can this type of question be made: *Where did the king reached up to*?

Comment: You _reach up to_ a high shelf to take something from it (stretch your arm), but when travelling you just _reach_ a place. Again, "How far did the king reach?" might be more idiomatic.

Comment: "Reach till" may be idiomatic in Indian English. In my dialect (US English), I would not generally use a preposition between "reach" and the destination of travel.

Comment: @nschneid Exactly. I've heard many people saying here. Particularly when someone wants to say that *go to up to particular point/destination*. However, when searching dictionary I could only see its usage as a preposition of time only. That confused me.